# Jquery ui sortable with connected lists

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

How can I connect 2 list so that I can only drop the items from list 1 into list 2, including placeholders  in list 2 but not in list 1.

I know there is `connectWith` but how could I prevent that the items can be reordered in list1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of the `stop` and `receive` events and by using the `cancel()` function:

```
$("#list1").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortables",
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        if ( $(ui.item).parent().is(this) ) {
            $(this).sortable("cancel");
        }
    },
    receive: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.sender).sortable("cancel");
    }
});
$("#list2").sortable({connectWith: ".sortables"});
```

Explanation: `stop` is used to check if sorting an element originating within the same widget; `receive` is used to check if sorting an element originating in other widgets.

Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hrvj2qnd/

Doc reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Thanks, is there way to prevent the placeholder in list1 as well?

Comment: What do you mean by *prevent the placeholder*?

Comment: The gap between to items when start dragging.

Comment: You can use the `placeholder` option and whatever css you want: http://jsfiddle.net/hrvj2qnd/1/ , http://jsfiddle.net/hrvj2qnd/2/

Answer (score 0):

Final solution: http://jsbin.com/volote/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
  connectWith: "#sortable2",
  helper: 'clone',

  placeholder: 'gap',
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  start: function(e, ui) {
    ui.item.show();
  },

  stop: function(e, ui) {
    if (ui.item.parent().is("#sortable1")) {
      $(this).sortable("cancel");
    }else{ 
     console.log(ui.item.text())
     console.log(ui.item.index())
    }
  },

  receive: function(e, ui) {
    if (ui.item.parent().is("#sortable2")) {
      console.log(ui.item.text())
      console.log(ui.item.index())
      ui.item.clone().insertAfter(ui.item);
      $(ui.sender).sortable("cancel");
    }
  }
})

$("#sortable2").sortable({
  helper: 'original',
})
```